# Handsontable - custom HTML header renderer - <select> tag issue

Tags: handsontable

I'm trying to add a 'select' (dropdown) tag in my handsontable custom header. The problem is, when I click on the dropdown, it does not stay open and I cannot select a different option.

The code looks like this:

```
colHeaders: function (col) {
  var txt;

  switch (col) {
    case 0:
      txt = `<select class='checker'>
              <option value="optionone">Option One</option>
              <option value="optiontwo">Option Two</option>
              <option value="optionthree">Option Three</option>
            </select>`;

      return txt;
  }
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle for this (I used the official example for custom header renderers, except i replaced the checkbox with a select tag):
https://jsfiddle.net/kjcm2y8f/

If anyone has an idea on how to fix this, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Updating your Handsontable version will help solve the problem. In your jsfiddle, replace your css with this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handsontable@7.0.1/dist/handsontable.full.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handsontable@7.0.1/dist/handsontable.full.min.css">
```